# Why can you overload getattr for a typing.Dict but not a typing_extensions.TypedDict?

Tags: python-3.x, operator-overloading, python-typing

I am using python 3.10, and switched from `Dict` to `TypedDict` for the annotations. Following the advice of [Pep 655](https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/#usage-in-python-3-11), I'm importing from `typing_extensions` instead of `typing`; I also want `NotRequired`, which can *only* be imported from `typing_extensions` at this version.

I've noticed that I can overload `__getattr__` (and `__getattribute__`) for `Dict`, `OrderedDict`, and even `typing.TypedDict` just fine, but that it is ignored for `typing_extensions.TypedDict` children. Why is this, and is there a way around it?

Example:

```
from typing_extension import TypedDict
from typing import Dict, TypedDict as TypedDict2

class PerfectlyFineDict(Dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key): return self[key]
class PerfectlyFineDict2(TypedDict2):
    def __getattr__(self, key): return self[key]


f = PerfectlyFineDict(a=1)
print(f['a']) # Of course, prints "1"
print(f.a) # Works perfectly fine - prints "1"

f = PerfectlyFineDict2(a=1)
print(f['a']) # Of course, prints "1"
print(f.a) # Works perfectly fine - prints "1"


class FailingDict(TypedDict):
    def __getattr__(self, key): return self[key]

f = FailingDict(a=1)
print(f['a']) # Of course, prints "1"
print(f.a) # AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I would rather not import `TypedDict` from `typing` and `NotRequired` from `typing_extensions`, since it seems to be against the PEP standard and I'm not sure how it will interact with the lexer (probably fine), but I'm not sure what the alternative is.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. I am getting the same error for `typing.TypedDict`.

Comment: I’m using python 3.10.11, and note that TypedDict needs to be important from ‘typing_extensions’ - does that help reproduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#class-based-syntax), under class based syntax

> Methods are not allowed, since the runtime type of a TypedDict object will always be just dict (it is never a subclass of dict).

And indeed

```py
f = PerfectlyFineDict2(a=1)
print(type(f))
```

shows that it is still just a `<class 'dict'>`.

You are simply only expected to use it as they describe

```py
class PerfectlyFineDict2(TypedDict2):
    stuff: int
    things: str
```

PyCharm was clever enough to detect this attempt and gave a yellow squiggly indicator with a helpful link to the exact explanation.

As far as I understand it, this class based syntax is just borrowing the syntax of inheritance, but it's really just meta-class black magic where anything goes.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting, especially since I’ve had certain lexers reject returning a TypedDict where a Dict is expected and want me to annotate it as a Mapping :( Probably a lexer implementation thing not a language thing, thanks for the PEP pointer!